# Create modern website that loads content without refresh

Tags: html

I'm trying to find useful tutorials about how to create modern websites that loads content without refreshing the page.

I have tried all kinds of words in Google, but I don't get any useful hits. Perhaps it's because I'm not sure what I should be searching for.

Tips and links to tutorials would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: These websites will use AJAX.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: Also have a look at those: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[html]+update+content+without+page+refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tl;dr:` Googling <kbd>[ajax website tutorial](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=ajax+website+tutorial&)</kbd> or <kbd>[jquery address tutorial](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=jquery+address+tutorial)</kbd> is a good start.

---

As has been noted, the key here is [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

AJAX alone, however, is not the answer.
It's pivotal to a non-page-reload site, but there are also a lot of other things to consider.

Luckily for us all, the Internet is great, and lots of developers have an *open-source is awesome* mindset.

Suffice to say, this type of site has been done before, and there are people out there who have made developing a site like this easier.

Ignoring the back-end & server-side setup, the way I would recommend starting a site like this is to use the following:

- [HTML5 BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com)
- [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plugin.

Use the plugin from the start; from experience, it's difficult to implement it after you've completed the site.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want use ajax. There are also ways to poll the server for updates as well. You can use a setInterval call to periodically retrieve a URL; but this is only required if you're polling. If you're doing this action based on a user event, you can just use that to trigger the retrieval/update. I'd suggest looking at jQuery, it'll make this kind stuff much easier.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Ajax would make it possible in a simpler way!

Answer (score 0):

There are frameworks built exactly for this. One of today's hot ones is [Meteor.js](http://www.meteor.com/).

Read about it. Worst case, you'll get your googling keywords and find an alternative you like.