# Open Link in html form without opening it in new window

Tags: javascript, html

i want to open the link like 'www.foo.com' in an html form (just like a pop up) not in new window. can i achieve this? if yes than how ? 
on button click action i just want to open a form which will trigger that link and show me that screen instead of ***opening in new window***.

```
<h1>HI I AM chatBOT</h1>


    <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
    <textarea placeholder="Type message.." name="msg" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>

    <input type ="hidden" value=""  id = "linkedPararm" name = "linkedPARAM" onchange="" />     
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Comment: You mean like a `modal` "window"?

Comment: Have you heard of AJAX? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create modern website that loads content without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763394/create-modern-website-that-loads-content-without-refresh)

Comment: @ObsidianAge nope i need to open url in a popup like form on button event not in a popup window or new tab

Comment: @dw_ yes something like that but how can i open a url in it ? in that modal window?

Comment: You can try something like this modal: https://micromodal.now.sh/ and then update its contents with an AJAX call.